# A quadratic polynomial getting square values in consecutive points

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In a book "Which Way did the Bicycle Go" there is the following problem:

Find a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ such that $p(1),p(2),p(3),$ and $p(4)$ are perfect squares but $p(5)$ is not.

Does anyone knows some generalizations of this? For example, are the following problems open:

1. Find all quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ such that $p(1),p(2),p(3),$ and $p(4)$ are perfect squares but $p(5)$ is not.
2. Find a/all quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ such that $p(1),p(2),p(3),\ldots, p(n-1)$ are perfect squares but $p(n)$ is not.

Comment: Your first "generalization" is just a copy of the original question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why? The original problem asks to find one polynomial. My first problem asks to find all of them.

Comment: Sorry, reading too fast. I've put up an answer linking to recent work on the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [paper](http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/engonz/research/papers/symmetric.pdf), Gonzalez-Jimenez and Xarles, On symmetric square values of quadratic polynomials, Acta Arithmetica 149.2 (2011) 145-159. From the introduction:

In this note we are dealing with the following problem. Given a degree two polynomial $f (x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ in ${\bf Z}[x]$ which is not a square of a degree one polynomial, how many consecutive integer values $f(i)$ can be squares in ${\bf Z}$? This problem has been considered by D. Allison in [1](http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/engonz/research/papers/symmetric.pdf) and [2], who found infinitely many examples with eight consecutive values, and by A. Bremner in [3], who found more examples with seven consecutive values.

Comment: It seems worth noting that the linked-to result concerns quadratics where the consecutive squares are symmetric, so that the first is equal to the last (or am I misreading something?), so it doesn't fully answer the OP's question.  See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338037/find-a-polynomial-as-2836x2-12724x16129 which asks more or less the same question.