# Find a polynomial as $2836x^2-12724x+16129$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I found a polynomial function with integer coefficients:$f(x)=2836x^2-12724x+16129$
and $f(0)=127^2,f(1)=79^2,f(2)=45^2,f(3)=59^2,f(4)=103^2,f(5)=153^2.$

My question is:can we find a polynomial function with integer coefficients,called $f(x)$,which has no multiple roots,and $f(0),f(1),f(2),f(3),……,f(k)$ are distinct square numbers?($k>5$ is a given integer)
Thanks all.

PS:I'm sorry,guys.I lost a very important condition:$f(x)$ should be a quadratic function:$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.($a,b,c$ are integers and $b^2-4ac≠0$)

So the Lagrange interpolation method does not work.

I wonder is there always such a quadratic polynomial when $k$ is arbitrarily large?

Comment: This post is relevant, more soon http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333253/a-quadratic-polynomial-getting-square-values-in-consecutive-points

Comment: @Andreas Caranti:Thank you,Andreas.

Comment: @Hecke I don't know if this interests you, but your example $2836x^2 -12724x+16129$ seems needlessly complex.  You can take $25+120 t-24 t^2$ or $1+100 t-20 t^2$ instead (each is square for the six values $t=0,\ldots, 5$).

Comment: @A Walker：Yeah,I found this example with a special method so the numbers are a little big..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One such quadratic 
$$p(t)=-4980t^2+32100t+2809$$
$p(0)=53^2,p(1)=173^2,p(2)=217^2,p(3)=233^2,p(4)=227^2,p(5)=197^2,p(6)=127^2$

Source : *Polynomials E.J Barbeau*

Comment: This is a good answer to k=6,I wonder is there always such a quadratic polynomial when k is arbitrarily large?

Comment: I have downloaded this book,thanks for your advice.

Comment: In that case the question is "Exploration E5" in the book.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting link is the following question:

[Least power. Squares again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306146/least-power-squares-again)

Quoting the answer given there by Ivan Loh:

> In the paper http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/poly2.pdf, it is proven that if a polynomial $P(x_1,x_2,…,x_n)\in \Bbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,…,x_n]$ is such that $P(n)$ is a perfect square for all choices of $x_1,x_2,…,x_n$ with $\lvert x_i \rvert \le c$, where $c$ is sufficiently large, then $P(x)$ must be the square of a polynomial.

See also [A quadratic polynomial getting square values in consecutive points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333253/a-quadratic-polynomial-getting-square-values-in-consecutive-points)

already mentioned in a comment.

Comment: :Thanks,I have knew this results before I asked this quetion.But I want to know how to find a polynomial which has  perfect values on some continuous points.

Comment: I think the wording here is not as clear as in the paper: the constant $C$ depends on the polynomial. So to be clear, while the paper is very interesting, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @simplequestions, I am aware of this, thanks. My quote was in the spirit of _related matter_.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) to find a polynomial with any (finite) set of values you want.

Comment: @Yoni Rozenshein:Thank you,but the polynomial is not alway with integer coefficients

Comment: @Hecke: but it will have rational ones, so you could rescale it by the square of the common denominator. Non-multiple roots seem to be of a bigger problem.

Comment: @Ilya：I understand,thank you.

Comment: Btw, what's wrong with $(x+1)^2$?

Comment: @YoniRozenshein: multiple roots?

Comment: Oh. finally I understood the problem. :P

Comment: How about $(x^2+1)^2$ ?

Comment: @Yoni Rozenshein. It still have multiple roots($x=\pm i$ both occurring twice). The idea "without multiple root" is just to indicate the polynomial is not a square of another polynomial(which would be trivial).

Comment: @YoniRozenshein: $\text{roots}(P(x)) = \text{roots}(P^n(x))$ since $p = 0$ iff $p^n = 0$

Comment: It has no real roots though. That seemed weaker than "is not the square of a polynomial". Okay then.

Answer (score 1):

Some brute force search gives $289 + 2940 t - 420 t^2$,
which satisfies
$$f(0)=17^2, \quad f(1)=53^2, \quad f(2)=67^2, \quad f(3)=73^2, \quad f(4)=73^2, \quad f(5)=67^2, \quad f(6)=53^2, \quad f(7)=17^2.$$
This is the only solution I've found for $k=7$.  I'll update this post if/when I can best it.

Comment: Thank you,But I prefer to see f(0),f(1)...f(k) are distinct numbers,and I have edited my questions.