# Prove that the equation $x^4+(2k^2)x^2+2k^4$ is not a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that any quadratic of the form $x^4+(2k^2)x^2+2k^4$ for any nonzero integer $k$ is never a perfect square for all integers $x$.

I thought about proving this by induction. We first prove that $x^4+2x^2+2$ is not a perfect square for all integers $x$ (which is true since $x^4+2x^2+2 = (x^2+1)^2+1$) and then proceed with the inductive hypothesis. Is there an easier way of solving this?

Comment: $f(0)=2k^4$ is never a perfect square.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, that is true.

Comment: Sorry, missed the `nonzero` part. Maybe related: [A quadratic polynomial getting square values in consecutive points](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/333267).

Comment: You're still fine, because $k$ is what has to be non-zero, to say nothing of $x$. In fact, if we allowed it to be so, that would break your example.